# How to draw geometric shapes on buttons

Tags: java, android

We are making a quiz app as a school project where we are supposed to display a question and show 4 answers. For 8 seconds we are supposed to show 4 buttons with different geometric shapes of different colors(and text for the answer). Then when the timer hits zero the geometric shapes will change colors and switch positions. Then the buttons should be clickable and we can hit the correct answer.

My problem is that I can't find a way to draw these objects on a button, or anything clickable. I could have just used images of triangles, circles etc. on ImageButton, but as the objects need to change colors, it will be difficult. Here is a photo of what it is supposed to look like:

(edit) https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Far.png

Hope someone can help me with this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Step 1

For creating geometrical shapes you will have to create a different xml file in the drawable folder for each shape. [for drawing circle you need to oval]. XML file should be like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="any_shape_name*" >

<stroke
    //optional: for setting border.
    android:dashGap="4dp"
    android:dashWidth="10dp"
    android:width="6dp"
    android:color="@color/black" />

<solid android:color="@color/white" />

<padding
    android:bottom="20dp"
    android:left="20dp"
    android:right="20dp"
    android:top="20dp" /></shape>
```

- Step 2

  Create a button in main layout file and add this xml as the background

  android:background = "@drawable/*shape_file_name*"

This was just a simple 2 step method.

**Note**:- You can also draw shapes dynamically and set them as the background of the button.
For this way please refer to [this beautiful link](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/shapes.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like this will work very well. Thank you very much!